# PMOS Gate Driver using BJT

Tags: bjt, gate-driving, pmos

I'm (again) looking at high-side load-switching. The load shall be switched on with a controlled rise-time (=limited inrush current) and be switched-off quickly when a controller (not shown) detects an error condition.

My problem with the typical slew-rate control circuit is the dependence of output-slew rate to supply voltage level. Also turn-off is slow since the gate is pulled up only by R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpVx0K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I came up with in response is the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLQyzN.png)</sup>

Q2 is there for fast turn-off. Addition of Q3 seems to solve the problem of supply dependent rise-rate - at least in LTSpice. **However, frankly don't know why.**

Apparently I'm using Q3 not as a switch, but in it's linear region to "regulate" the current through R2, but the component values are made up by trial and error and I would like understand the matter. Could someone also comment on temperature influence?

Comment: Couldn't you do this with MOSFETs?

Comment: @KGregory maybe, but why would this be better? Could you please clarify?

Comment: 1) They typically switch faster and have higher input impedance. 2) You already have a mosfet, so you could potentially eliminate a line item from your BOM (if that one is suitable for the switching circuit)

Comment: @KGregory I understand your point.  However,  the main issue I try to solve is a constant output rise irrespective of input voltage.

Comment: Q1 and Q2 provide fast turn off. Q3 is the pulldown device, and it gets rid of the supply dependence since is is a ground referenced common emitter instead of a vin referenced follower...

Comment: Those all look like terrible ways to turn on a pmos.  (I'm sorry to say the only good way I know involves an opamp.) You could decrease the R's in the first circuit by ~100 and get rid of C1.  1K into 10 ohms, with some R in the base so you can drive it... assuming you can waste 1mA of current.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your opamp suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Q3 is operating in one of two distinct modes, depending on whether its collector is higher than or lower than the voltage on the `EN` signal.

When the collector voltage is higher (right after turn-on), it functions as a constant-current sink, with the current determined by the emitter voltage (which is one diode drop below the base voltage) across R2.

However, when the collector voltage drops too low to sustain this voltage across R2, then the base and emitter voltages also drop and Q3 just functions as a saturated switch.